# Firebase onChildAdded adds duplicate entries to the list this makes the length of the list differ

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

My app is for the driver, who delivers orders through this application. In this, I am listening to all the orders assigned to the driver from the firebase realtime database. The onChildAdded.listen adds the order to a list named ongoingList of class Ongoing which means assigned to him. I am then displaying the length of the list as count in the dashboard. Now sometimes I am getting unexpected counts in the dashboard and also the list contains duplicate entries.

**I am adding the code below**

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isOnline = true;
  var OngoingDetails;
  List<Ongoing> ongoingList = [];
  List<OpenRequest> openRequestList = [];
  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  late StreamSubscription<Event> ongoingStream;
  late StreamSubscription<Event> openRequestStream;
  late StreamSubscription<Event> removeOpenNodes;
  late LocationData currentLoc;
  double currentLat = 0;
  double currentLng = 0;
  DriverDetail _driverData = DriverDetail();

  // late Timer timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // timer =
    //     Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 300), (Timer t) => reloadPageAuto());
    getDriverData();
    countOpenRequest = 0;
    ongoingCount = 0;
  }

  reloadPageAuto() {
    // Navigator.pop(context); // pop current page
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/dashboard'); // push it back in
  }

  getDriverData() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    _driverData = await getDriverDetails();
    print("${_driverData.driverName}");
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
    //getCurrentLocation();
  }

  getCurrentLocation() async {
    currentLoc = await getLoc();
    setState(() {
      currentLat = currentLoc.latitude!;
      currentLng = currentLoc.longitude!;
      isLoading = false;
    });
    // checkOpenRequest();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime timeBackPressed = DateTime.now();
    return isLoading == false
        ? DefaultTabController(
            child: WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: () async {
                final difference = DateTime.now().difference(timeBackPressed);
                timeBackPressed = DateTime.now();
                if (difference >= Duration(seconds: 1)) {
                  final String msg = 'Press the back button again to exit';
                  showToast(msg);
                  return false;
                } else {
                  Fluttertoast.cancel();
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                  return true;
                }
              },
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  leading: Switch(
                    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.grey,
                    value: isOnline,
                    activeColor: kWagonColour,
                    onChanged: (value) async {
                      setState(() {
                        isOnline = value;
                        //print(isOnline);
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          msg: isOnline == true
                              ? "You are now Online"
                              : "You are now Offline",
                          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          backgroundColor: kWagonColour,
                        );
                      });
                      if (isOnline == true) {
                        await OneSignal.shared.disablePush(false);
                        OneSignal.shared
                            .setAppId("abd31b6b-5fc4-4769-8684-224a439e422e");
                        final status = await OneSignal.shared.getDeviceState();
                        var playerId = status!.userId;
                        OSCreateNotification notification =
                            OSCreateNotification(
                          androidChannelId:
                              "1ff1eb80-0316-419f-bd37-0992145ee37d",
                          heading: "Go Wagon Driver",
                          playerIds: [playerId.toString()],
                          content: "Background Service Active",
                          androidSound: "onesignal_default_sound.wav",
                          iosSound: "onesignal_default_sound.wav",
                        );
                        OneSignal.shared.postNotification(notification);
                        SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
                            SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
                        ));
                      } else {
                        //print('else');
                        await OneSignal.shared.disablePush(true);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  actions: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_driverData.image),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profile');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Image.asset(
                    'images/app_icon.png',
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                  ),
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.home,
                              color: kWagonColour,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                              child: Text('Home'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.price_change_outlined,
                              color: kWagonColour,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                              child: Text('Earnings'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                    labelColor: kWagonColour,
                    indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: kWagonColour),
                      insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                    ),
                    indicatorColor: kWagonColour,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                body: isLoading
                    ? ColorLoader()
                    : GestureDetector(
                        child: TabBarView(
                          children: [
                            Status(
                              details: ongoingList,
                            ),
                            Earnings(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                floatingActionButtonLocation:
                    FloatingActionButtonLocation.startFloat,
                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => QRCodeScanner(),
                    ));
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.qr_code_scanner,
                    color: kWagonColour,
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            length: 2,
            initialIndex: 0,
          )
        : Scaffold(
            body: ColorLoader(),
          );
  }
}

class Status extends StatefulWidget {
  const Status({Key? key, required this.details}) : super(key: key);
  final List details;

  @override
  _StatusState createState() => _StatusState();
}

class _StatusState extends State<Status>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Status> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  var top = 10.0;
  var left = 10.0;
  DriverDetail _driverData = DriverDetail();
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isLoadingCount = true;
  List<Ongoing> ongoingList = [];
  List<OpenRequest> openRequestList = [];
  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  late StreamSubscription<Event> ongoingStream;
  late StreamSubscription<Event> openRequestStream;
  late StreamSubscription<Event> removeOpenNodes;
  late LocationData currentLoc;
  double currentLat = 0;
  double currentLng = 0;
  bool _enabled = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDriverData();
  }

  getCurrentLocation() async {
    currentLoc = await getLoc();
    setState(() {
      currentLat = currentLoc.latitude!;
      currentLng = currentLoc.longitude!;
    });
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
    checkOpenRequest();
  }

  checkOpenRequest() async {
    print("checking open request");
    if (countOpenRequest == 0) {
      setState(() {
        isOpenRequest = false;
      });
    }
    print("open count $countOpenRequest");
    countOpenRequest = 0;
    openRequestStream = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('shipments')
        .child('open_requests')
        .orderByChild('model_id')
        .equalTo(double.parse(_driverData.modelId))
        .onChildAdded.listen(_onEntryAddedOpen);
    //     .listen((event) {
    //   double total_distance = distance(
    //       currentLat,
    //       currentLng,
    //       double.parse(event.snapshot.value['pickup_latitude']),
    //       double.parse(event.snapshot.value['pickup_longitude']),
    //       'K');
    //   print("distance for ${event.snapshot.key} $total_distance");
    //
    //   if (total_distance <= 50) {
    //     HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
    //     setState(() {
    //       // print("New request received: ${event.snapshot.value}");
    //       ++countOpenRequest;
    //       isOpenRequest = true;
    //     });
    //   }
    // });
    checkOngoing();
  }

  checkOngoing() async {
    print("checking ongoing");
    ongoingStream = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('shipments')
        .child('driver_shipments')
        .child(_driverData.vehicleId)
        .onChildAdded
        .listen(_onEntryAddedOngoing);
    setState(() {
      isLoadingCount = false;
    });
  }

  getDriverData() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    _driverData = await getDriverDetails();
    getCurrentLocation();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // timer.cancel();
    openRequestStream.cancel();
    ongoingStream.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    var deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Card(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      AutoSizeText(
                        'Hi, ${_driverData.driverName}',
                        minFontSize: 16,
                        maxFontSize: 20,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'What do you want to do today?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50.0,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.replay_circle_filled,
                      color: kWagonColour,
                      size: 40.0,
                      semanticLabel: 'Refresh',
                    ),
                    onTap: _enabled ? refreshCounts : null,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              OngoingShipments(ongoingDetails: ongoingList),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: deviceWidth / 7,
                          height: 40,
                          child: Center(
                            child: isLoadingCount == false
                                ? Text(
                                    ongoingList.length.toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: kWagonColour,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => OngoingShipments(
                                    ongoingDetails: ongoingList),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'ONGOING',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: kWagonColour,
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 20,
                  left: deviceWidth / 1.8,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => TestFirebase()));
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => TestFirebase()));
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'OPEN',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: kWagonColour,
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 60,
                          height: 40,
                          child: Center(
                            child: isLoadingCount == false
                                ? Text(
                                    openRequestList.length.toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: kWagonColour,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  refreshCounts() {
    setState(() {
      isLoadingCount = true;
      _enabled = false;
    });

    isLoadingCount = true;
    ongoingList = [];
    openRequestList = [];
    ongoingCount = 0;
    countOpenRequest = 0;
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        _enabled = true;
      });
      checkOpenRequest();
    });
  }


  _onEntryAddedOngoing(Event event) async {
    setState(() {
      ongoingList.add(Ongoing.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
    });
    

  }
  _onEntryAddedOpen(Event event) async {
    double totalDistance = distance(
        currentLat,
        currentLng,
        double.parse(event.snapshot.value['pickup_latitude']),
        double.parse(event.snapshot.value['pickup_longitude']),
        'K');
    print("distance for ${event.snapshot.key} $totalDistance");

    if (totalDistance <= 50) {
      HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
      setState(() {
        openRequestList.add(OpenRequest.fromFirebase(event.snapshot));
      });
      
    }



  }
}
```

**Below is the code for my class Ongoing**

```
Ongoing(
      {this.baseFare,
        this.cancelationFee,
        this.customerId,
        this.customerName,
        this.distanceTotal,
        this.driverId,
        this.driverImage,
        this.driverName,
        this.driverNumber,
        this.driverNumberCode,
        this.dropAddress,
        this.dropLatitude,
        this.dropLongitude,
        this.estimatedTime,
        this.helpCount,
        this.helpTotal,
        this.isPayable,
        this.itemCount,
        this.masterFlag,
        this.minHr,
        this.minKm,
        this.modelId,
        this.payableFlag,
        this.paymentMethod,
        this.paymentStatus,
        this.perHr,
        this.perKm,
        this.pickPayPaymentStatus,
        this.pickupAddress,
        this.pickupCode,
        this.pickupLatitude,
        this.pickupLongitude,
        this.pickupTime,
        this.price,
        this.pricePerHr,
        this.pricePerKm,
        this.receiverName,
        this.receiverPhone,
        this.receiverPhoneCode,
        this.senderName,
        this.senderPhone,
        this.senderPhoneCode,
        this.shipmentId,
        this.shipmentLabel,
        this.shipmentLabelAr,
        this.shipmentOtp,
        this.shipmentPackageInstruction,
        this.shipmentPackageName,
        this.shipmentPackagePropertyId,
        this.shipmentPackageTypeId,
        this.shipmentPolyline,
        this.status,
        this.total,
        this.type,
        this.vehicleId,
        this.vehicleName,
        this.wagoncut,
        this.isCashShipment,
        this.invoiceNumber,
        this.invoiceDate,
        this.invoiceAmount,
        this.operationMobile, this.packageName}); 

  Ongoing.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    baseFare = snapshot.value['base_fare'];
    cancelationFee = snapshot.value['cancelation_fee'];
    customerId = snapshot.value['customer_id'];
    customerName = snapshot.value['customer_name'];
    distanceTotal = snapshot.value['distance_total'];
    driverId = int.parse(snapshot.value['driver_id'].toString());
    driverImage = snapshot.value['driver_image'];
    driverName = snapshot.value['driver_name'];
    driverNumber = snapshot.value['driver_number'];
    driverNumberCode = snapshot.value['driver_number_code'];
    dropAddress = snapshot.value['drop_address'];
    dropLatitude = snapshot.value['drop_latitude'];
    dropLongitude = snapshot.value['drop_longitude'];
    estimatedTime = snapshot.value['estimated_time'];
    helpCount = snapshot.value['help_count'];
    helpTotal = snapshot.value['help_total'];
    isPayable = snapshot.value['is_payable'];
    itemCount = snapshot.value['item_count'];
    masterFlag = snapshot.value['master_flag'];
    minHr = snapshot.value['min_hr'];
    minKm = snapshot.value['min_km'];
    modelId = snapshot.value['model_id'];
    payableFlag = snapshot.value['payable_flag'];
    paymentMethod = snapshot.value['payment_method'];
    paymentStatus = snapshot.value['payment_status'];
    perHr = snapshot.value['per_hr'];
    perKm = snapshot.value['per_km'];
    pickPayPaymentStatus = snapshot.value['pick_pay_payment_status'];
    pickupAddress = snapshot.value['pickup_address'];
    pickupCode = snapshot.value['pickup_code'];
    pickupLatitude = snapshot.value['pickup_latitude'];
    pickupLongitude = snapshot.value['pickup_longitude'];
    pickupTime = snapshot.value['pickup_time'];
    price = snapshot.value['price'];
    pricePerHr = snapshot.value['price_per_hr'];
    pricePerKm = snapshot.value['price_per_km'];
    receiverName = snapshot.value['receiver_name'];
    receiverPhone = snapshot.value['receiver_phone'];
    receiverPhoneCode = snapshot.value['receiver_phone_code'].toString();
    senderName = snapshot.value['sender_name'];
    senderPhone = snapshot.value['sender_phone'];
    senderPhoneCode = snapshot.value['sender_phone_code'].toString();
    shipmentId = snapshot.value['shipment_id'];
    shipmentLabel = snapshot.value['shipment_label'];
    shipmentLabelAr = snapshot.value['shipment_label_ar'];
    shipmentOtp = snapshot.value['shipment_otp'];
    shipmentPackageInstruction = snapshot.value['shipment_package_instruction'];
    shipmentPackageName = snapshot.value['shipment_package_name'];
    shipmentPackagePropertyId = snapshot.value['shipment_package_property_id'];
    shipmentPackageTypeId = snapshot.value['shipment_package_type_id'];
    shipmentPolyline = snapshot.value['shipment_polyline'];
    status = snapshot.value['status'];
    total = snapshot.value['total'];
    type = snapshot.value['type'];
    vehicleId = snapshot.value['vehicle_id'];
    vehicleName = snapshot.value['vehicle_name'];
    wagoncut = snapshot.value['wagoncut'];
    isCashShipment = snapshot.value['is_cash_shipment'].toString();
    invoiceAmount = snapshot.value['invoice_amount'].toString();
    invoiceNumber = snapshot.value['invoice_no'].toString();
    invoiceDate = snapshot.value['invoice_date'].toString();
    operationMobile = snapshot.value['operation_mobile'].toString();

  }
  
}
```

If anyone has relevant suggestion regarding it, please help me through it. Thank you in advance